# Regex pattern skips last matches and misses content with parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string:

```
r'pat1=a, pat2=b, (e, e*89=f), bb, pat3=c, pat4=hi, pat10=ex'
```

I need to extract patterns as:

```
pat1=a, 
pat2=b, (e, e*89=f), bb, 
pat3=c, 
pat4=hi, 
pat10=ex
```

This is the pattern I tried:

```
re.findall(r'(pat\d*.*?)[(pat\d*)|$]', s)
```

which gives me:

```
['pat1=', 'pat2=b, ', 'pat3=c, ', 'pat1']
```

I am more interested in knowing how exactly my pattern is working here that it did not match the required string. Also what could be the solution.

Comment: Maybe `re.split(r',\s*(?=pat\d+=)', s)`?

Comment: can you suggest something around the pattern I tried or something which is not so complex

Comment: `re.findall(r'pat\d+=.*?(?=pat\d+=|$)', s)`? What do you mean by "not so complex"? See https://ideone.com/v7YdKs. But this is really much more complex that just splitting with a comma followed with whitespaces, `pat`, digits, `=`.

Comment: gives `[]` empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `(pat\d*.*?)[(pat\d*)|$]` matches `pat` and optional digits, then as least as possible chars until it matches **one of** the listed characters in the character class `[(pat\d*)|$]`

To get your desired matches, you don't want to match anything after `.*?` but you want to assert either the start of a part with the same pattern for `pat`.

And for the last part, you can assert the end of the string.

---

You could write the pattern as:

```
\bpat\d+=.*?(?=\s*\bpat\d+=|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bpat\d+=` Match the word `pat` followed by 1+ digits and `=`
- `.*?` Match as least chars as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert to the right

  - `\s*\bpat\d+=` Match optional whitespace chars, then `pat`, 1+ digits and `=`
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string for the last part
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h5U80A/1)

Comment: Can you explain this regex, also could you please explain how my regex was working

Comment: @Himanshuman I have added an explanation for both.

Comment: Parenthesis actually matches the group, if we use this `\bpat\d+=.*?` at the beginning won't that also look for the pattern at the beginning of every match, if that is the case how does it match `pat1` pattern

Comment: @Himanshuman The pattern has no match with a grouping, the `(?=`  part is an assertion. If you only use `\bpat\d+=.*?` then the `.*?` part at the end will settle matching an empty string because there are no more rules in the pattern.